# Non-surjective but injective real polynomial functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Over algebraically closed fields $K$, the [Ax–Grothendieck theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem) (see also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662293/polynomial-map-is-surjective-if-it-is-injective?rq=1)) states that injective polynomial functions $K^n \to K^n$ in $n$ variables are surjective. Is there a simple counterexample for this statement for real polynomial functions *i.e.* $K=\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4):

The statement of the theorem holds even for $k=\mathbb{R}$. See the article

Białynicki-Birula, A., Rosenlicht, M.: [Injective Morphisms of Real Algebraic Varieties](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2034464).

Answer (score -3):

A polynomial function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is either of odd degree and surjective, or of even degree and not injective.

Comment: Right, but maybe I should clarify. A *polynomial function* is a function $f\colon k^n \to k^n$ where $k$ is a field and $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, $f_i \in k[x]$.

Comment: This answer suggests that this cute question has been answered which is not the case...

Comment: @Kwinto $n=1$ here...

Comment: Najib, I think you get something wrong with the quantifiers...