# Example for an injective but not surjective polynomial $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

The Ax-Grothendieck theorem claims that every injective polynomial function $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ is surjective. A proof using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz can by found in Terry Tao's blog [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/infinite-fields-finite-fields-and-the-ax-grothendieck-theorem/). Since the latter theorem holds for algebraically closed fields, I tried to look at what happens to the former theorem, if $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ are taken instead. The first case is simple, $\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q},x\mapsto x^3$ is injective, but not surjective (It's quite funny, that you can use Fermat's last theorem to prove $2$ doesn't have a preimage.). The second case seemed as well, every injective polynomial $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has to be surjective because of different limits for $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ and the intermediate value theorem, so there is no counterexample, but I think there should be for $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,n>1$. After hours, I still haven't found one though. I tried using the Binomial theorem, but examples like $P\colon(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-y^2,x-y)$ (which doesn't work as $P(1;1)=P(2;2)$) or $(x,y)\mapsto(x(x-y),y(x-y))$ (which doesn't work as $P(x,y)=P(-x,-y)$) just don't fit. Using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and the sufficient conditions for being injective and not surjective unfortnutly isn't allowed when considering fields that aren't algebrically closed. I still have the feeling, that there is a simple and elegant counterexample I just don't see? None of the literature for the Ax-Grothendieck theorem I read featured one.

Is there an injective, but not surjective polynomial $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,n>1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-surjective but injective real polynomial functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966482/non-surjective-but-injective-real-polynomial-functions-mathbbrn-to-mathbb)

Comment: @BartMichels I don't think it does.

Comment: @BartMichels Thanks, it's interesting I missed this question when searching. According to this link, the theorem still holds for $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. In this case, I would look for a counterexample in higher dimensions.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz The linked article is for all $n$. See §3, page 201.

Comment: @BartMichels Unfortnutly I can't access page 201 as I'm not registered yet. But I'll do so on occasion and give it a look.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz Does this link work? https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2034464.pdf&hl=en&sa=T&oi=ucasa&ct=usl&ei=unlmYuXoGIuKmgGY1YjABQ&scisig=AAGBfm2XkBlGWsIkiZzEJSqkl7hM7eEjlw

Comment: Downloading link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0140516-5/S0002-9939-1962-0140516-5.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiX57Hyh6_3AhXm_7sIHe8ACqgQFnoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw11mXSZzqbHaaF1zB-ucvbV

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks! I really did not guess the Ax-Grothendieck theorem also holds for $\mathbb{R}$.