# Using Model-Theoretic Proof of Ax-Grothendieck for the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, model-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

A proof of Ax-Grothendieck utilizes model theory and the fact that the theorem is true for finite fields, and also algebraic closures of finite fields. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662293/polynomial-map-is-surjective-if-it-is-injective?).

I have a (perhaps naive) question: considering that the Riemann hypothesis has been proved over finite fields, is it possible to utilize the approach to prove the Riemann hypothesis over $\mathbb{C}$?

I'm guessing the answer is a sound "no," otherwise it would've been done already.  Where does the argument fail? Is it in writing the Riemann hypothesis in first order logic, or something with the ideas?

Comment: in the book by Patterson on RZ (and in later references that I do not remember exactly, but quoted Patterson anyway) there is an observation that trying to extrapolate the finite fields results and what they imply leads to a combinatorial problem that has solutions in complex numbers that do not satisfy the conditions required for RH, so in other words the implied finite field results (which hold for rational functions after all) are way too weak for the transcendental (and universal so very complicated) complex zeta; check Patterson chapter on the topic for the exact details

Comment: In Ax--Grothendieck a basic ingredient is that polynomials have _finitely_ many terms, so the assertion can be written as a first-order sentence.